# Prove that a finite p-group G is simple if and only if its order is p.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't understand how to solve this problem. I don't think I'm allowed to assume its abelian. Also, I know that I will have to use this theorem: If $p$ is a prime and $G$ is a $p$-group with more than one element, then $Z(G)\neq \{1\}$.

Comment: Sorry, it is a duplicate of [A finite $P$-group cannot be simple unless it has order $p.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2012626/a-finite-p-group-cannot-be-simple-unless-it-has-order-p). The center is always a non-trivial normal subgroup, as you said. If the group has order $p$, it is abelian. This is easy to prove, too (just Lagrange).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't understand how to go in the forward direction. How does G being a finite p-group and simple mean its order is p? I understand the other direction.

Comment: If $G$ is a simple $p$-group, then its center is a proper normal subgroup - a contradiction, except if $G=Z(G)$ (because $Z(G)=1$ is impossible).