# Prove that if $|G|=p^n$, for some prime number $p$, then there exists a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $p^m, m\le n $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

> Prove that if $|G|=p^n$, for some prime number $p$, then there exists a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $p^m, m\le n $.

---

My first attempt was to use the proposition below, but I figure that the stabilizer is not a normal subgroup, and I wasn't sure if I can use this without having a set to act on.

Can I use the proposition that says if $|G|=p^n$ and $G$ acts on a set $X$ then $|X|=|X^G| \pmod{p}$, where $X^G=\{x\in X \mid \forall g\in G,  gx=x\}$

On $G$ itself ?

Meaning, can I write $
\def\st{\operatorname{st}}
|G|=|\st(x)|\pmod{p}$?
Where $\st(x)$ I denote the stabilizer of $G$

My second attempt was to use the fact that the center is a normal subgroup and maybe that will do it by using: $$
|G|=|Z(G)| \;{}+ \sum_{|o(x)|>1} \frac{|G|}{|\st(x)|}
$$

Where  $o(x)$ is the orbit and $Z(G)$ is the center.

Comment: Mod out by a central subgroup of order $p$ and use induction on $n$.

Comment: This is equivalent to your claim: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2012626/943729 and the proof is induction-free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Work by induction on $m$.  Assume $n \gt 1$.  First note that the class equation assures you that $Z(G)$ is non-trivial, so it must have an element of order $p$, which in turn generates a normal (because central) subgroup $N$ of order $p$.  In other words, any such group must have a normal subgroup of order $p^1=p$.  That's the base case for our induction.

Now consider $G/N$.  If $1 \lt m \lt n$, then $\vert G/N \vert = p^{n-1} \gt p^{m-1} \gt 1$ and by our inductive hypothesis, $G/N$ has a normal subgroup of order $p^{m-1}$, which corresponds to a normal subgroup of $G$ containing $N$ with order $p^m$.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the last part of your proof, "which corresponds to a normal subgroup of G containing $N$ with order  $p^m$" why is that true, how we get that ?

Comment: It's *Theorem C* here (often called the Third Isomorphism Theorem): https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Isomorphism_theorems

Comment: Is it easy for you to verify my answer below ?

Comment: @lupusnox Why can't it be the case that $Z(G)=G$?  More importantly, I think you've been asked to prove that such a normal subgroup exists for each $m \leq n$.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\st{\operatorname{st}}
|G|=|\st(x)|\pmod{p} \Rightarrow |\st(x)|=p^{i_x},i_x\in \{1,...,n-1\}$

$$
|G|=|Z(G)| \;{}+ \sum_{|o(x)|>1} \frac{|G|}{|\st(x)|}
$$

$$ p^n=|Z(G)|+\sum_{|o(x)|>1}p^n/p^{i_x}$$

$$ |Z(G)|=p^m\left(p^{n-m}-\sum_{|o(x)|>1}p^{n-m}/p^{i_x}\right),$$ where $m=\min\{i_x\}$.

Thus $$p^m\mid |Z(G)|,$$

where  $o(x)$ is the orbit and $Z(G)$ is the center.

Comment: @Shaun is my answer correct ?

Comment: I'm not sure what allows you to conclude $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $p^m$ from $p^m\mid |Z(G)|$.

Comment: @Shaun the center $Z(G)$ isn't a normal group ?

Comment: It is, yes, but I still don't follow.

Comment: @Shaun and since $p^m$ divides the center, it's a subgroup with at least $p^m$ elements, but because $|G|=p^n $, the center from Lagrange has to be only of the order $p^m,p^{m+1},...,p^n$

Comment: @Shaun and it exists a normal subgroup with order $p^k$, the center. My answer doesn't tell if it's exist another rather than the center, is that the problem ?

Comment: I think I follow. Thank you.

Comment: @Shaun thanks for verifying!

Comment: Hang on, wait; I'm not sure anymore. How come such a subgroup exists?